# Navbar works only one time on rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I'm doing an app on rails and I have a problem with my navabar.
I took it on bootstrap and when I click on one of my links it works only the first time, if I click in an other link it redirect me to the home section. I have to actualize to make link work again but again only for the first click.
Do you have a solution for that ? 
Here is my code :

```html
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg ">
    <h3 class="navbar-brand"></h3>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
        aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <%=link_to "Accueil", '#view', class:"nav-link"%></li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <%=link_to "A propos", '#about', class:"nav-link"%>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <%=link_to "Compétences", '#skills', class:"nav-link"%>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <%=link_to "Etudes", '#education', class:"nav-link"%>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

My four section have an id with the right name.

Thanks a lot.

EDIT : Thank you all, I find the answer.
I had a old link to a .css file that didn't exist anymore in my . When I erase it the navbar works.
My mistake !

Comment: Is there any javascript involved here? That should just generate plain old anchor links so it does not make sense that the browser would go to another element. Try to help us help you by providing a complete example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: No Js but I find the solution, I had an old link in my head, always a bad thing to have. Thank you for you answer

Answer (score 0):

Try use `<li><%= link_to "Etudes", product_path(anchor: 'education') %></li>` instead of `<li><%=link_to "Etudes", '#education'%></li>`

From [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html)